# Rails migration won't create NOT NULL constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have this db migration for my Rails 3.2 plugin:

```
class CreateIssueChangeApprovements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :issue_change_approvements do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.references :issue, :null => false
      t.references :user, :null => false
      t.string :field_type, :limit => 30
      t.string :old_value
      t.string :value
      t.integer :approved_by_id
      t.boolean :is_closed, :default => 0
      t.string :status, :default => '', :limit => 30
    end
    add_index :issue_change_approvements, :issue_id
    add_index :issue_change_approvements, :user_id
  end
end
```

Once I run it against a MySQL database, I see no NOT NULL constraints on `issue_id` and `user_id` fields as well as no foreign keys.

Can anyone tell me what is the right way to do this?

**UPD:**

The weird thing here is that when I go to MySQL Workbench and generate a script for my newly created table, i get this:

```
CREATE TABLE `issue_change_approvements` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `issue_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved_by_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_closed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_issue_change_approvements_on_issue_id` (`issue_id`),
  KEY `index_issue_change_approvements_on_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

However when I run a statement like this:

```
insert into issue_change_approvements(value) values('hello')
```

it executes successfully and adds a row with lots of NULL values.

**UPD 2:**
This is what `describe issue_change_approvements` shows:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| issue_id       | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field_type     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| old_value      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| approved_by_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_closed      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| status         | varchar(30)  | YES  |     |         |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please include the table you are changing, preferably after the above migration.

Comment: @onebree, there is no table. It is a `create_table` migration

Comment: What do you get when you try ```describe issue_change_approvements;``` in your mysql console?

Comment: I guess you have not sql_mode  `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` enabled, otherwise you would have recieved an error on your insert statement.
check sql_mode var by running `show variables like "sql%"`. mysql 5.6.4
deafult is
 `set sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails does not create any constraints by default. The `null: false` option will just not allow null values for this sql field, but it will not add a constraint.
Instead of foreign_key constraints in rails you usually just set the desired option on model relationship, e.g `has_many :issues, dependent: :destroy`
I guess this strategy was chosen for faster schema migrations with less downtime.

However there is an option to use constraints on db level by explicitly specifying them. You can use the `foreigner` gem prior to rails 4.2 and with rails 4.2 the dsl for them is included by default.

See
[Have Some (Referential) Integrity with Foreign Keys](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys)

[2.5 Foreign Key Support](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support)

Comment: So all these checks exist on app level only and I need to add them explicitly in order to propagate them down to DB level, right?

Comment: Yes, more or less. They do not exist by default on app level either. You have to setup this behavior on app level, by proper usage of associations.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. Like setting `dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: My experience is that setting ```null: false``` will add a database level constraint. This is different to an app level constraint, which must be added to the model as a validation.

Comment: null: false, just creates a NOT NULL column e.g `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN user_id NOT NULL `
As i came to rails i couldn't believe it,  too, but actually this strategy of having constraints on app level rather than db level works pretty ok for the most rails apps. This is also the reason, why the feature to propagate them to db level was introduced that lately.

Comment: Foreign key referential integrity should be used alongside 'not null', as stated in the included article. The fact that the 'not null' constraint isn't working is puzzling.

Comment: @dre-hh: I have seen many Rails apps where lack of 'not null' constraints have caused issues. Not just with associations, but data columns and query results. When you can't trust the data you can't trust the app. However, the permissive nature of Rails means that these constraints are seldom used, so adding them can really confuse some very popular plugins. (Shoulda and RailsAdmin come to mind.) Using non-null columns and so-called 'null objects' in code leads to better, more robust and more accurate applications.